# Prevent all html tags except <img>

Tags: php, regex, xss

In order to prevent XSS attacks to my site i use `PHP regex` like

```
$regex = '/[<>]/';
$preg_replace= ($regex, '', $text);
```

With this codes i delete `<` and `>` charaters so problem is done. However now i want that user can add `<img>` tag into my site while other tags like `<script>`must still be forbidden.How can i do that?

[What i've tried](http://likes.bestofsimpson.com/uploads/2421fcb1263b9530df88f7f002e78ea5.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using regexes for this? What's the matter with `strip_tags`, or a better tool like html purify? the only thin you're going to accomplish with regexes is corrupting your html, and almost certainly NOT plugging the holes you're trying to plug.

Comment: `<img>`, too, is a big risk for XSS-attacks. you should not allow that without thoroughly validating user input.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann how this could be possible i want to hear that.

Comment: @WebberDepor: Franz Gleichmann is right, you can have an overview here: http://html5sec.org/

Comment: @WebberDepor for example with `<img src="http://example.com/user/deletemyaccount.php">`

Comment: @webber `<IMG src="x" onerror="sendEveBobsCookies()">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:
http://htmlpurifier.org/

If that is not what you search, you can do this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
strip_stags($string, '<img>');
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` i will use that

Comment: @webber removing all tags except img doesn't prevent xss, though. One can still append event handlers to it. And even if you fix that, people can still point the image to their server and they'll know exactly who has seen the image they've pointed you at.